# I'd like a homework pizza with everything on it, but no loops

Tags: code-golf

So there was a ["please do my homework question" on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709248/i-dont-understand-loops-in-python?noredirect=1#comment27566575_18709248) that lead to an idea. As everyone knows loops are quite expensive, in some places they can get as high as $12.99 an iterations, so to save money there shouldn't be any loops.

So, [lets do the homework](http://eecs.wsu.edu/~slong/cpts111/labs/lab3.pdf), but in the least intuitive way.

> Write a program that decides, among competing candidate pizzas, which is the
>   best deal, in the sense of the smallest cost per unit area. Pizzas come in three shapes:
>   round, square, and oval (elliptical). The area of an oval is `pi*ab/4`, where:
>    `a` and `b` are the longer and shorter dimensions of the oval.

<del>The rest of the specifications are in the linked PDF, which I can add in if needed. The input and output should conform to the assignment.</del>

As per breadboxes suggestion the I/O has changed a bit to be more golfy.

- Your program must accept input for each pizza (lower case is a literal, uppercase is an argument):

  - **In all of the below**: `C` is the cost for that pizza in drachma (a float), and all units of length are in attoparsecs (~3cm).
  - `C s L` - a *square* pizza, with a size length L
  - `C r D` - a *round* pizza, with **diameter D**
  - `C o L S` - an *oval* pizza, with long side L and short side R, all ovals have an area of `pi*L*S/4` (for some reason).
  - An empty string denotes that there are no more pizzas.
- For each pizza, print out the area in attoparsecs, a literal `@` and the cost in Drachma per square attoparsecs (just numbers, units not required).
- After the user indicates there are no more pizzas, print the index of cheapest pizza (starting at 1).
- Pi may be approximated to 3.1415

An example run would be (`>` indicates input, `<` is output, but these don't need to be printed to screen):

```
> 13.59 r 14.2
< 158.37 @ 0.086
> 14.04 s 12.3
< 151.29 @ 0.093
> 12.39 o 14.1 8.3
< 91.92 @ 0.135
>
< 1
```

Spaces are optional in output, but the `@` symbol must be in the output of the pizza

**However, you can't use any *traditional* loops.** Recursion, `goto`s or list comprehension are all fine, but any thing that is syntactically a loop like a `for`, `while` or `do ... while` are all strictly forbidden.

**Shortest code wins.**

Comment: Do we want to adhere strictly to the lab's I/O? I suspect that those strings are going to wind up being the majority of everyone's character counts. It would be more to the spirit of codegolf if the I/O boilerplate could be downplayed. (Minimized, not in the codegolf sense of reduced to an absolute minimum, but in the sense of de-emphasized.) Either way, though, it would really improve the description if a complete sample session was included.

Comment: @breadbox I've changed the rules and I/O a little to make it more golfy. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Does Ruby's `Array#each` (and other languages' equivalent constructs) count as a traditional loop, or as array comprehension? What about Ruby's `while` modifier that is technically a loop but it's written after the statement?

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm not well versed with ruby, but `Array#each` sounds in the spirit of the challenge, however `while` seems like it is not as it sounds like a `do...while`. Even if not its a token that sounds loop-ish.

Comment: I assume Java's `for(Type elem:collection)` counts as array comprehension?

Comment: Can we use `22/7` as the approximation?

Comment: @JanDvorak `for` looks like a loop so, no - not allowed. `22/7` it was good enough for Archimedes, so sure why not.

Comment: "all ovals have an area of pi*L*S/4 (for some reason)" You'll notice that if `L == S` then this formula is `pi * (2r)^2 / 4` which is `pi * r^2`. Essentially, this is just a generalization of the formula for the area of a circle. It's generally expressed as `pi * a * b`, where `a` and `b` are the semimajor and semiminor axes (i.e., half of `L` and `S`).

Comment: @user202729 I didn't think of that, since nobody pointed it out in the comments, and I didn't think of it while reading (replying to chat)

Answer (score 3):

## HTML/JavaScript, 160 bytes

(linebreaks/indentation only added here do prevent scrolling)

```
<input onchange='window.n++||(n=1,L=1e9);s=this.value.split(" ");d=s[2];
        a=[5.5/7*d*(s[3]||d),d*d][1*(s[1]=="s")];c=s[0]/a;alert(a!=a?m:a+"@"+c);
        L<c||(L=c,m=n)'>
```

The input is a text box (press Enter to submit); the output is an alert box.

A few caveats (or cheats, if you will):

- Pi/4 is 5.5/7
- in some cases, it assumes that the pizzas have non-zero areas
- it's not possible to enter the same pizza twice in a row (because that won't trigger a `change` event)
- note that defocusing the input also counts as "enter"
- assumes that at least one pizza costs less than a billion Drachmas per square attoparsecs
- no fault tolerance for the input whatsoever
- you could argue that it's not qualified because it uses the browser's event loop

Comment: +1 - The code doesn't say `for`, `while` or `loop`. Using the browser seems like a legit abuse of the rules.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Should note that I wrote this in response to prompting in the original stackoverflow question's comments.  So it attempts to exactly follow the homework assignment (which was supposed to be done in Python and produce specified output).  As such, it does not follow the updated golf-like rules.

So its absolutely not the shortest (repeats a lot of code), but it doesn't do any loops and it does some stupid things

```
def pizza(list,n):
    n = n + 1
    print 'Pizza Number ' + str(n) + ':'
    shape = raw_input('Pizza shape (round, square, oval):')
    if shape == 'oval':
        longer = float(raw_input('Pizza longer dimension:'))
        shorter = float(raw_input('Pizza shorter dimension:'))
        price = float(raw_input('Pizza price:'))
        area = (3.1415 * longer * shorter)/4
        print 'Pizza area is %.2f square inches' % area
        cost = price/area
        print 'Cost per square inch is $%.2f' % cost
        listing = '%d (OVAL %.2f x %.2f)' % (n,longer,shorter)
    elif shape == 'square':
        side = float(raw_input('Pizza side length:'))
        price = float(raw_input('Pizza price:'))
        area = side**2
        print 'Pizza area is %.2f square inches' % area
        cost = price/area
        print 'Cost per square inch is $%.2f' % cost
        listing = '%d (SQUARE %.2f x %.2f)' % (n,side,side)
    else:
        shape = 'round'
        diameter = float(raw_input('Pizza diameter:'))
        price = float(raw_input('Pizza price:'))
        area = 3.1415 * (diameter / 2)**2
        print 'Pizza area is %.2f square inches' % area
        cost = price/area
        print 'Cost per square inch is $%.3f' % cost
        listing = '%d (ROUND %.2f)' % (n,diameter)
    list[listing]=cost
    another = raw_input('Enter Another? (Y/N):')
    if another == 'Y':
        pizza(list,n)
        return list
    else:
        return list
dict=pizza({},0)
print 'The best deal is pizza number ' + min(dict, key=dict.get)
```

-Validates shape entry by assuming you want round if you enter anything else.

-Uses 3.1415 to avoid importing a library

-Assumes you are done if you enter anything besides 'Y'

-Every pizza is stored as a unique dictionary key.

Other than the things I intentionally did in a stupid way or to avoid a traditional loop, I'm open to any criticisms as I am not an accomplished python programmer.

Comment: I think doing things in intentionally stupid ways is part of the fun of being a golfer!

Comment: Well, I submitted my solution to the course's professor so we will see what he says.  Although I now notice that the course was being taught in Python 3 so I don't think my program will work as expected (I know there's some changes with input/raw_input).

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 251

Definitely not the shortest, but a good indication of whats required.

```
def p():
 i = raw_input().split(' ')
 if['']==i:return
 f=float;C=f(i.pop(0));S=i.pop(0);P=3.1416;a=f(i[0])
 if's'==S:A=a**2
 elif'r'==S:A=P*(a/2)**2
 elif'o'==S:A=P*a*f(i[1])/4
 c=C/A;print A,'@',c
 return[c,p()]
P=p()[:-1];print P,P.index(min(P))+1
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 167 bytes

```
def p():
 try:return[eval("{2}*dict(s={2},r={2}*.7854,o={3}*.7854)['{1}']/{0}".format(*(raw_input()+' 1').split()))]+p()
 except:return[]
v=p()
print v.index(max(v))+1
```

Using the constant *0.7854* to approximate *π/4*.

Sample usage:

```
$ more in.dat
13.59 r 14.2
14.04 s 12.3
12.39 o 14.1 8.3

$ python homework-pizza.py < in.dat
1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <del>128</del> <del>132</del> 141 characters

```rb
b,j,i=1/0.0,1
$<.map{|s|j+=1
c,s,x,y=[*z=s.split,0].map &:to_f
b,i=c,j if b>c
p"#{a={?s=>x*x,?r=>x*x*=0.7854,?o=>x*y}[z[1]]}@#{c/a}"}
p"#{i}"
```

Borrowed `0.7854` from Primo. It's more precise than `3.1415/4` anyways.

User indicates there are no more pizzas by closing the STDIN stream. Yes, CTRL+D works in the jRuby interactive console. Yes, you have to restart the console to reopen the stream.

---

Cool facts about Ruby:

Destructuring assignment: you can assign an array to a list of variables. If you try to pass a non-array, it will be converted to an array first. In case of non-array-likes, that's a single-element array containing that element. If the array is too short, extra variables are set to `nil`. If the array is too long, some elements are discarded. Here we assign `nil` to `i` for scoping reasons only.

Ruby's selling points are iterators and methods with callbacks in general. To be enumerable, all you have to do is to implement `each` and inherit the right methods. This challenge forbids traditional loops, but it allows array comprehensions. STDIN is an input stream, and as such it is enumerable. As a bonus, input stream comprehension sets the globals `$_` (last line) and `$.` (line number) for us. Line 3 demonstrates the pretzel colon operator which constructs a block for the iterator.

Some find modifiers (`do_something until it_is_done`) confusing. I like them. Be careful that the order of evaluation (and of side-effects) is reversed, however. String interpolation - if overdone (like here) - can get messy at times (like here), and syntax highlighters can choke on nested interpolation (or give up completely, like here). Literal dereference. Just write a literal, and read from it immediately. Any decent language can do that (I owe an apology to PHP 5.3 at this point).

Of course, subexpression caching. As soon as an expression is long enough long or occurs frequently enough, stuff its value into a variable. Ruby's assignment has a low priority from the right, but high priority from the left. Thus, `a*b=c*d` assigns `c*d` to `b`. Also, carefully rearranging computation can let us alias variables. While normally a horrible thing, it can save characters when golfing because it lets one (ab)use the compound assignment operators. Unfortunately, it only works with operators.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I can't get this to run at all. `1.8.7`, `1.9.3` and `2.0.0` all report `undefined method \`split' for nil`. Changing line 2 to `$<.map{|s|z=s.split` results in `nil can't be coerced into Float`, once again, in all three versions. Also, for what it's worth, the proper stream termination character on a windows machine seems to be `^Z` (at very least, PHP, Perl, Python and Ruby all seem to like it).

Comment: @primo I was testing in JRuby IRB Console [1.7.3 (1.9.3)]. Maybe it only works in IRB? CTRL+Z doesn't work for me in the jRuby console.

Comment: same `nil to float` coercion error in jruby: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UVwZz.png

Comment: @primo confirmed. Will debug.

Comment: @primo fixed. That's what I get for not testing every change.

Comment: A few more issues, unfortunately... 1) Ruby1.9.3 and Ruby2.0.0 both still require `|s|z=s.split` to run at all. 2) Ruby1.9.3 and Ruby2.0.0 do not report the best value, but rather the pizza with the lowest cost. 3) jRuby will always report `1` (this can be easily confirmed by adding a `p$.` to the <s>loop</s> comprehension).

Comment: @primo #2 is a misunderstanding of the rules. This can be fixed easily. As for #1 and #3 - can I claim jRuby IRB the platform? It works perfectly there.

Comment: I don't mean to rag on this, I think it's a very good solution, just not quite functional. A small modification makes a valid 1.9.3, and 2.0.0 solution (130 bytes): http://ideone.com/shS0nf You could claim a jRuby platform, but `$.` always coming back as `1` isn't very helpful.

Comment: @primo oh well. Fixed #1 and #2, but #3 got very expensive.